# How to make label with this layout? (see screenshot)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uilabel

[image: Sample]

So I need to make a view with thumbnail image (dark gray) and a text label, the problem is the label spans after and below the thumbnail, is there a way to do this without splitting the text into two labels or using rich text for the whole thing?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using iOS 7, the TextKit will serve you greatly. Take a look at the 2013 WWDC video  "Introducing Text Kit" (#210) plus "Advanced Text Layouts and Effects with Text Kit" (#220) and download the sample code to checkout their layout demo.

In the PDF slides for #210, take a look at slides 84 and 98. In the second video, take a look at the beginning slides / part of the video.

**Note:** I'm not giving direct links since iOS 7 has only been announced, but not released until the 18th.

Comment: Sorry I am using iOS 6

Comment: Bummer. I guess you could try using indents in your text, but that is a bit fragile. I think your best bet is to run calculations and split it up into 2 UILabels. The method `sizeWithFont:forWidth:lineBreakMode:` on `NSString` will be pretty handy. Just note that that method is going to be deprecated in iOS 7. Hope this helps!